# Analysing sentence structure

Tags: sentence-structure

Please help me understand why the use of "human as" is wrong in the following sentence:

> [...] the philosophers emphasized the study of human as fundamental to their doctrine."

Comment: Consider this:  Botany is the study of plant.  No.  Botany is the study of plants.

Comment: I think people are looking for editing and hide that my saying things like analyzing sentence structure. Personally, I don't mind. the study of human beings.

Answer (score 1):

The Philosophers aren't just emphasizing the studying one human, they are emphasizing the study of **all** human**s**. Since they are emphasizing the studying more than one *thing* the *thing* is plural.

Please see this [article](https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-plurals.php).